# CSS Selectors returns null with Puppeteer & JS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, xpath, css-selectors, puppeteer

I'm trying to use CSS selectors for classes with dynamic class names and id's. So far, if I'm using `XPATH`, the code works. If I'm using css selectors in the website console, such as

`document.querySelectorAll('main > div > div > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(1)')`,

it returns the correct div with the inner text that I want inside. Although, in javascript, by running the following function:

`title: article.querySelector('main > div > div > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(1)').textContent;`

it returns null.

What am I missing? I would try to work this code with XPATH but I have no idea how to loop through more XPATHS and send them togheter as a `payload`.

Comment: because you use article instead of document?